# Disabling certain warnings in distcc

Tags: c++, distcc

I'm using plain distcc (without pump mode) to compile my code,
and for each file that is distributed to the host, the following message is printed:

```
distcc[11543] (dcc_talk_to_include_server) Warning: INCLUDE_SERVER_PORT not set - did you forget to run under 'pump'?
distcc[11543] (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: failed to get includes from include server, preprocessing locally
```

is there anyway I can disable this warning?
I didn't 'forget' to run under pump, since my code includes boost headers, it fails to preprocess on my host anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the hosts file (`~/.distcc/hosts`) from this: `host/8,lzo,cpp` to this: `host/8` helped.

`lzo,cpp` is required for pump mode to work. Thus, it seems like it is detecting the capabilities of the server as supporting pump mode. Hence the warning that it should and could be enabled.